# Output specific fields using bash

Tags: bash, fasta

I have a test.fasta file with the following data:

```
>PPP.0124.1.PC lib=RU01 length=410 description=Protein description goes here 1 serine/threonine  
MLEAPKFTGIIGLNNNHDNYDLSQGFYHKLGEGSNMSIDSFGSLQLSNGG
GSVAMSVSSVGSNDSHTRILNHQGLKRVNGNYSVARSVNRGKVSHGLSDD
ALAQ
>PPP.14552.PC lib=RU01 length=104 description=Protein description goes here 2 uncharacterized protein LOC11441
MKSVVGMVVSNKMQKSVVVAVDRLFHHKLYDRYVKRTSKFMAHDEHNLCN
IGDRVRL
>PPP.94014.PC lib=RU01 length=206 description=Protein description goes here 3 some more chemicals and stuff
MDLGPTLTLQKGRQRRGKGPYAGVRSRGGRWVSEIRIPKTKTRIWLGSHH
SPEKAARAYDAALYCLKGEHGSFNFPNNRGPYLANRSVGSLPVDEIQCIA
AEFSCFDDSA
```

I would like to take the ID and the description and output them into a `.tsv` file, with the first column being the ID and the second column holding the description.

Desired output:

```
| ID | Description |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 0124    | Protein description goes here 1 serine/threonine           |
| 14552   | Protein description goes here 2 uncharacterized protein LOC11441            |
| 94014 | Protein description goes here 3 some more chemicals and stuff |
```

Any ideas on a one-line Bash command to achieve this?

I currently have this:

```
grep -a '^>' test.fasta |
awk '{print $1}
```

which gives me the first lines and the ID's but cant seem to figure out the rest!

Comment: If you could post the expected/desired output, then that would be nice, so the rest of us could understand more...

Comment: Header columns:
(ID | Description)

(0124 | Protein description goes here 1 || serine/threonine)
(14552 | Protein description goes here 1 ||  uncharacterized protein LOC11441)
(94014 | Protein description goes here 3 || some more chemicals and stuff)

Comment: Not in the comment section, please update your question/post.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I've updated it. When editing the table shows up but now that i've saved it the table doesn't seem to be showing anymore

Comment: Requiring a one-line solution is dubious. An arbitrarily complex command line can be made a "one-liner" by replacing newlines with semicolons or other similar formatting tricks; but ignoring that, sometimes a solution which requires a few lines of code is simply more idiomatic or elegant than a forced one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple `sed` script:

```
sed -n 's/^>[^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*description=/\1\t/p' test.fasta
```

This simply looks for a line which begins with `>` and perhaps some non-numbers followed by numbers, followed by `description=` somewhere later on the line, and replaces that part with just the numbers and a tab, and prints the resulting line.

(This assumes the first sequence of digits on the line is the ID. It alse requires that your `sed` interprets `\t` as a literal tab, which isn't entirely portable.)

The same could easily be recast into Awk, though it's arguably less elegant.

```
awk -F . 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
    /^>/ { d=$0; sub(/.*description=/, "", d); print $2, d }' test.fasta
```

which assumes the interesting part of the ID is between the first and second dots always, and avoids the [useless `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).

This declares dot as the field separator with `-F .` and the output field separator `OFS` as tab, then extracts everything after `description=` from the original input line `$0` into the variable `d` on lines which begin with `>`, then prints the second field and `d`.

I had to guess some requirements; if my guesses are wrong, please edit your question to clarify exactly how the numeric ID should be extracted, for example.

Comment: Awesome!! The awk command works perfectly, however the sed command is giving the following error: sed: 1: "/^>[^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]* ...": invalid command code \. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I understand it may take some time, but could you please explain the different parts to each of the awk/sed commands? It would be really helpful! Cheers:)

Comment: Sorry for the typo; fixed that, and added brief explanations. These languages are not hard to learn, so the explanations  are rather terse - just read a basic tutorial if you want to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "id\tdescription"} \
/.PC / && !/uncharac/ { \
split($1,b,"."); id=b[2]; \
$1=""; $2=""; $3=""; $(NF)=""; $(NF-1)=""; $(NF-2)=""; \
gsub("description=",""); print id"\t"$0} \
/.PC / && /uncharac/ { \
split($1,b,"."); id=b[2]; \
$1=""; $2=""; $3=""; $(NF)=""; $(NF-1)=""; \
gsub("description=",""); print id"\t"$0}' test.fasta

id  description
0124       Protein description goes here 1 || serine/threonine   
14552      Protein description goes here 2 || uncharacterized protein LOC11441  
94014      UProtein description goes here 3 || some more chemicals and stuff
```

Since the description can span `n` columns, you need to remove 'known', unwanted columns.  In your test data there seem to be records that can be differentiated by 'uncharacterized protein' or not.  Records that have 'uncharacterized protein' only need to have 2 trailing columns removed, while other records need to have 3 trailing columns removed.

Parse the id from the first column: `split($1,b,"."); id=b[2];`

Remove unwanted columns: `$1=""; $2=""; $3=""; $(NF)=""; $(NF-1)=""; $(NF-2)="";` OR `$1=""; $2=""; $3=""; $(NF)=""; $(NF-1)="";` (if uncharacterized protein).

Clean the description by removing 'description=':  `gsub("description=","");`